# Select many columns error entity framework (Unable to create a null constant value of type)

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I don't want all columns to be returned so I'm trying to select some columns from EMPLOYEES, I got an error when running the following code:

```
    var query = db.EMPLOYEES.AsQueryable();
query = ApplyFilter(query, filter);

var result = query.Select(x => new EMPLOYEE_DTO()
{
     PHONE_NO = x.PHONE_NO,
     EMAIL = x.EMAIL,
     EMP_NO = x.EMP_NO
}).ToList();

private IQueryable<EMPLOYEE> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<EMPLOYEE> query, EmployeesFilter filter)
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.EMAIL))
       query = query.Where(u => u.EMAIL.ToLower().Contains(filter.EMAIL.ToLower()));
    return query;
}
```

The error is:   {"Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context."}

I saw a post saying that using DTO object (EMPLOYEE_DTO) will solve the issue but the issue still exist.

Please advice.

Comment: To understand whether the problem is in your query or in your Select, what happens if you do `query.ToList()`?

Comment: I thought that the problem in the DTO object but it was happening also without using the DTO. The problem were in a filter value that comes null in ApplyFilter function "query = query.Where(u => filter.SelectedIds.Contains(u.EMP_NO)); ". The SelectedIds were null. Thank you for your hint, it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't tell us a lot about your classes. I assume that `filter` is an `EmployeesFilter` object in your local process; `db` is an object of type `DbContext`; and `db.Employees` is an object of `DbSet<Employee>`.

Both `filter` and `Employee` have a string property `Email`

Every `DbSet<Employee>` implements `IQueryable<Employee>`. So why are you calling `AsQueryable`?

Your `filter` is a local variable. In this context only `filter.Email` is important. If the value of this property equals null, you want all `Employees`, otherwise you want a subset of the `Employees`, namely only those `Employees` that have an `Email` value equal to the `Email` value in filter, ignoring Case.

Now ignoring case is always dangerous. After all, not everyone has names with only letters A-Z and a-z. It is better to describe what case ignorance you want: ordinal? current culture? invariant culture?

It seems you want the following:

```
var query = String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Email) ?
    db.Employees :
    db.Employees            
      .Where(employee => String.Equals(employee.Email, filter.Email, 
           StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

I'm not sure if changing this into an extra function like ApplyFilter would improve readability, but if you really want, write it as an extension function for `IQueryable<Employee>`:

```
static IQueryable<Employee> ApplyFilter(this IQueryable<Employee> employees, 
       EmployeeFilter filter)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Email) ? 
           employees :
           employees.Where(employee => String.Equals(employee.Email, filter.Email, 
               StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Usage for any query:

```
IQueryable<Employee> someEmployees = ...
IQueryable<Employee> filteredEmployees = someEmployees.Filter(myFilter);
```

I deliberately didn't use `var`, so you could see what happens to the types.

TODO: check if this code is correct by adding `ToList()` to see if the `Employees` can be fetched. But of course you already did that, didn't you?

Now your second part. So you have a query that returns an `IQueryable<Employee>` and you want to project every `Employee` into an `EmployeeDto`. If you want to do this in your query, you'll have to make sure that your `EmployeeDto` is a POCO: a class with a default constructor and only get / set properties.

If that is the case you should be able to perform your projection:

```
var result = query.Select(employee => new EMPLOYEE_DTO()
{
     PHONE_NO = employee.PHONE_NO,
     EMAIL = employee.EMAIL,
     EMP_NO = employee.EMP_NO,
})
.ToList();
```